# Windows 10 batch unzip multiple files with filename the same as zip directory name

Tags: batch-file, zip, unzip, 7zip

I have about 60 files to unzip as you can see below:

[image]

I know the 7zip option, which can unzip all of them, but the problem is, that the file inside doesn't match the zip directory name, which would be highly desirable here.

I found some solutions for the batch file here:

https://superuser.com/questions/371384/extract-all-zips-in-a-directory-incl-subfolders-with-a-bat-file-or-dos-comm

and prepared some batch code for this which looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
for %%a in (*.zip) do (
    Call :UnZipFile "C:\my\Desktop current\Occ KMZ\bat\Aldebaran" "C:\my\Desktop current\Occ KMZ\bat\Aldebaran"
)
exit /b
```

but it doesn't work at all. I can neither unzip it nor get files.

The 7zip software has a few options, which potentially could be good

[image]

but I don't know how to use the 7Zip command line in order to get the unzipped file with the same name as the zip directory.

What should I do to automatize this section?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something (minimal) that should work. Some parts can be done better (error handling and so on). 
It unzips each archive into a *dir* named like the archive but without the (*.zip*) extension.

*script00.bat*:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set EXE_7Z="c:\Install\pc064\7Zip\7Zip\Version\7z.exe"

for %%g in ("%~dp0*.zip") do (
    call :unpackFile "%%g"
)


goto :done


:unpackFile
    set _ARCH_DIR="%~dp1%~n1"
    rmdir /q /s %_ARCH_DIR% 2>nul
    %EXE_7Z% x -o%_ARCH_DIR% %1 >nul 2>&1
    goto :eof


:done
    echo Done.
    goto :eof
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f q071380369
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is 00000068 AE9E:72AC
> E:\WORK\DEV\STACKOVERFLOW\Q071380369
>     file00.zip
>     file01.zip
>     script00.bat
>
> No subfolders exist
>
>
> [prompt]> q071380369\script00.bat
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f q071380369
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is 0000006E AE9E:72AC
> E:\WORK\DEV\STACKOVERFLOW\Q071380369
> |   file00.zip
> |   file01.zip
> |   script00.bat
> |
> +---file00
> |       kkt.py
> |
> \---file01
>         URLs.txt
> ```